# Video For Everybody/PrettyPhoto Flash Fallback in IE keeps playing audio after video is removed

Tags: internet-explorer, prettyphoto, flash-video

I am attempting to use "Video For Everybody"/"PrettyPhoto", but have an issue in IE where the Flash fallback causes audio to keep playing after the video is closed/removed.

Has anyone experienced this or know how to solve the problem?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem in all browser for pretty-photo video light-box plugin.

Here is solution:

```
e.prettyPhoto.close = function () {
         if ($pp_overlay.is(":animated")) return;
         e.prettyPhoto.stopSlideshow();
         $pp_pic_holder.stop().find("object,embed").css("visibility", "hidden");
         $pp_pic_holder.find("iframe").attr("src", "");

and code continue.......
```

Answer (score 3):

I was having this issue when prettyPhoto fails to stop video in IE browsers. 
I fixed it removing container not making it visible (by default) so in Close Function add this line:
`if($.browser.msie)  {$pp_pic_holder.stop().find('object,embed,iframe').remove(); }`

At line 479 you will find prettyPhoto.close function

---

```
$.prettyPhoto.close = function(e){
        if($pp_overlay.is(":animated")) return;
        $.prettyPhoto.stopSlideshow();
        $pp_pic_holder.stop().find('object,embed').css('visibility','hidden');
        if($.browser.msie)  {$pp_pic_holder.stop().find('object,embed,iframe').remove(); }
```

---

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
if ($.browser.msie) {
    $pp_pic_holder.stop().find("object,embed,iframe").attr("src", "");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

its work for me
only upgrade the plugin to 3.1.5 and add rel=prettyphoto