# PrettyPhoto for videos keeps playing sound in IE9 when lightbox closed

Tags: internet-explorer-9, lightbox, prettyphoto

I am using prettyPhoto 3.1.5 and jquery-1.8.3.min (have also tried jquery-1.6.1.min).

I am using PrettyPhoto on videos (youtube). In IE9 when the lightbox is closed, the audio continues to play.

I have not edited the source code, so it's not something I have done. I have attempted to use a few different codes I have found that were supposed to fix this issue, but they only made the lightbox fail to work. When the videos are clicked on the change in the code merely treated the lightbox as a link and directs to youtube.

I tried to use the code on this page: 
[Video For Everybody/PrettyPhoto Flash Fallback in IE keeps playing audio after video is removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12783219/video-for-everybody-prettyphoto-flash-fallback-in-ie-keeps-playing-audio-after-v)

However, I was unclear what code to replace with the suggestion as there no match in the prettyPhoto 3.1.5 code.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

it work for me
only upgrade the plugin to 3.1.5 and add rel=prettyphoto